# Sveltekit: Have '@' symbol in route name without using named layouts

Tags: routes, sveltekit

I have a route in my `src/routes` folder called [user]@[server]

After upgrading sveltekit it throws an error: 'Named layouts not allowed in directories'.

The syntax for using named layouts uses the '@' symbol, but I want to have a literal '@' symbol in my route, that the user has to type into their url bar in the browser. Is there any way to do that in the newest version of sveltekit?

Answer (score 0):

For it to work it needs to be url encoded.

So `@` becomes `%40`

In your case the file's name might be something like: `[user]%40[server].svelte`